# Protractor typescript VScode debugging

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, protractor

I'm trying out protractor with typescript and was struggling to debug tests with VScode.

Browser opens when test starts, debugger stops at the debug point (after get url and couple of clicks and sendkeys statements), but browser is blank (url specified is not opened and non of the actions for which code executed happened in browser!). When I resume the test execution all the steps in test happen!

Launch.json

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Working thru node",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/protractor",
        "args": [
            "protractor.conf.js"
        ],
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "outputCapture": "std"
    }
]}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "outDir": "output",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["jasmine", "node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
   },
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*"]
}
```

Config.ts

```
import {Config} from 'protractor';
export let config: Config = {

   framework: "jasmine",
   capabilities: {
       browserName: "chrome"
   },
   specs: ["specs/*.js"],
   seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
};
```

SampleTest.ts

```
enter code here
import { browser, element, by, protractor, $ } from "protractor";

describe("Super Calculator", function(){

   beforeEach(function(){
       browser.get("https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/");
   })

   it("Should be able to add two positive numbers", function(){
       element(by.model("first")).sendKeys(1);
       element(by.model("second")).sendKeys(1);
       element(by.id("gobutton")).click();
       var Ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
       browser.wait(Ec.not(Ec.presenceOf($(".ng-valid-parse"))));
       expect<any>(element(by.binding('latest')).getText()).toEqual('2');
   })
})
```

Running test with

```
 npm run tsc && protractor output/config.js
```

My debug point is at last line of the test, execution stopped at debug point but non of the actions specified above that statement happened in browser. when I resume test, test ran and passed! I was expecting to see browser with url open and sendkeys and click happened when execution stopped at debug point! Can anyone help me understand what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I am a new one learning protractor in VSCode recently, also met this problem. This maybe something related to asynchronous. I recommend to debug in chrome inspector,
http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging#disabled-control-flow . Anyway, debugging in protractor is not as easy as in other language.